# Datasheet LM7812

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, datasheet

I'm confused: does the [LM7812](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7800.pdf) require at least 500 mA or not to output 12 volts at 1 amp? Help me understand what this part of the datasheet means:

[image: datasheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of test conditions given at the top of the electrical characteristics section are meant to provide context for how the measurements were determined or taken.

The \$I_O\$ spec is output current for any of the specifications where it isn't otherwise provided.

For the output voltage, \$V_O\$, there are two conditions provided. The first is just the junction temperature \$T_J\$ at ambient/25°C. For this condition, with the test circuit implemented, the output voltage is given as ranging from 11.5 to 12.5 V. When this range was determined, the output or load current was 500 mA, per this information. It does not mean that 500 mA is *required* to achieve this voltage, but that this amount of range (12 ±0.5 V) was determined using that amount of current.

At lower load currents, given in the second condition as 5 mA to 1 A*, the voltage output range is about 100 mV wider, from 11.4 to 12.6, or 12 ±0.6 V.

** With other conditions in effect as well.*